# Slow performance with CosmosDB DocumentDB and SqlAPI in c#

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to run a query that returns about 30,000 items from a `CosmosDB` collection. To execute this query within the code I post, the execution time is around 2 and a half minutes and even increasing throughput by 40x you don't get a substantial improvement, the time goes down to 1 minute.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsCompact(string whereclause)
{
    string collectionToUse;
    SqlQuerySpec sqlQuerySpec = new SqlQuerySpec();

    if (typeof(T).ToString().IndexOf("Telemetry") != -1)
    {
        DocumentDBRepository<CosmosDBTelemetry>.Initialize();
        collectionToUse = AppSettings.Collection;
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText = "SELECT c.messageUID as messageUID, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "c.deviceId as deviceId, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "udf.UDF_VIn(c.VIn) as VIn, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "udf.UDF_AIn(c.AIn) as AIn, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "udf.UDF_W(c.W) as W, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "udf.UDF_Var(c.Var) as Var, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "c.EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "from Telemetry c ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += whereclause;
    }
    else
    {
        DocumentDBRepository<CosmosDBEvents>.Initialize();
        collectionToUse = AppSettings.Collection2;
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText = "select doc.uid as uid, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.deviceId as deviceId, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.eventId as eventId, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.ts as ts, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.startTS as startTS, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.endTS as endTS, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.no as no, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.params as params, ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "doc.tags as tags ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "from Events doc ";
        sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += whereclause;
    }

    FeedOptions opt = new FeedOptions
    {
        EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
        MaxItemCount = -1
    };

    IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(

    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(AppSettings.Database, collectionToUse), sqlQuerySpec,opt).AsDocumentQuery();

    List<T> results = new List<T>();

    while (query.HasMoreResults)
    {
        results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
    }

   return results;
  }
```

Can someone help me in order to improve the performances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally expected. Cosmos DB is not meant to be used like that. You are performing a cross partition query. This ideally should never happen at least not in your application's normal logic. On top of that you are setting the `MaxItemCount` to `-1`. This means that you expect Cosmos to return everything in a single page. This is not recommended since Cosmos DB is only returning paginated results and that's when it's at it's best. You can change the page size to something like `100-250` but that still wouldn't improve your performance significantly. Cosmos DB is just not meant to perform in this scenario.

Comment: In my code I've commented **MaxItemCount** and I obtained some improvements. My collection in CosmosDB has over 500000 items. How can I select a subset  with performance results ?

Comment: The only way to have a scaleable select is to always select by a specific partition key value. If you select with a cross partition query then there is no way to make it faster and it will only become worse as you add more documents.

Comment: do you mean the partition key at design time? Or can we specify a partition key also at runtime?

Comment: You can specify the partition key in the query. You need to put it's value in the `FeedOptions` object.

Comment: For example **PartitionKey=new PartitionKey("/deviceId")** if the field is deviceId ?

Comment: @SimoneSpagna More like `PartitionKey=new PartitionKey("/theActualDevideIdValue")`

Comment: So should I specify deviceId as a partitioning key field at design time?

Comment: If that's the value they you need to query against then yeah

Comment: Is there a way to export all data from a collection and import it into one with the correct partition key?

Comment: Yes you can use the [Cosmos DB Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data)

Comment: I created the new container with the correct partition key, I imported the data, I tried to rerun the query indicating in the code the partitionvalue but it still takes 1 minute. Why?

Comment: Cuz you have half a million records and a complicated query.

Comment: I transferred 49875 records . 
Could it be the continuous calls to the udf to degrade the performance?

Comment: Try to enable query metrics and see what those tell you.

Comment: Yes. The uds are too time consuming. I dropped all from the query .......